# Bash date subtraction +%H:%M:%S

Tags: bash, date, variables

I looked all over online and can't seem to find anything that addresses what I am trying to do.  I am using Bash on an Unbuntu VM.
I created the following script

```
start_code=$(date +%H:%M:%S)
end_code=$(date +%H:%M:%S)
echo $start_code
for i in {1..1000};
 do echo $RANDOM >> filename.txt;
done
echo $end_code
```

The code works fine, but is there any way that I can subtract the variables start_code from end_code??

I have tried this many different ways one being total_code=$(($start_code - $end_code))
but I get errors or nothing returned with everything that I have tried.  As I'm brand new to Bash and I'm not even sure if I can do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to subtract timestamps, it is much easier if they are in a simpler format.  eg, an epoch as returned by `date +%s`

Comment: Or even bash's own timer variable [`$SECONDS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-SECONDS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to compute time lapsed.  You can do the subtraction with something like:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/sh

foo() {
        # This function does stuff
        sleep ${1-2}
}
start=$(date +%s)
foo 3
end=$(date +%s)

echo "time lapsed: $((end - start))"

time foo 4
$ ./a.sh
time lapsed: 3

real    0m4.006s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
```

In the above, we first store a time stamp before calling the function `foo` that just sleeps for 3 seconds.  Then we compute a new time stamp and subtract.  Then we do the same using the `time` builtin and let the function sleep for 4 seconds.

Comment: @Mr.Mongo, have a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and welcome to S.O.